# C++ - free crashes on reassigned pointer of pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

It's my first time being here and I am new with coding.
I am trying to make a Matrix class,

```
//Matrix.hpp
#ifndef __MATRIX_H__
#define __MATRIX_H__
class Matrix{
private:
    unsigned int m_row, m_column;
    unsigned int** matrix;

public:
    Matrix(unsigned int row, unsigned int column);
    ~Matrix();

    void transposeMatrix();

    void fill(unsigned int x);
    void fill_x(unsigned int row, unsigned int column, unsigned int x);
    void setMatrix(unsigned int** mat);

    bool isValid(unsigned int row, unsigned int column);

    unsigned int getRowNum();
    unsigned int getColumnNum();
    unsigned int get_x(unsigned int row, unsigned int column);
    unsigned int** getMatrix();

};
#endif
```

in Matrix.cpp file:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdbool>
#include "Matrix.hpp"

bool Matrix::fail = false;

Matrix::Matrix(unsigned int row, unsigned int column){
    m_row=row;
    m_column=column;

    matrix = new unsigned int*[row];
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++){
        matrix[i]=new unsigned int[column];
        for(int j=0; j<column; j++){
            matrix[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix(){
    for(int i=0; i < m_row; i++){
        free(matrix[i]);
        matrix[i]=NULL;
    }
    free(matrix);
    matrix=NULL;
}

void Matrix::transposeMatrix(){
    Matrix tmp_matrix(m_column, m_row);
    for(int i=0; i < m_row; i++){
        for(int j=0; j< m_column; j++){
            tmp_matrix.fill_x(j, i, this->get_x(i, j));
        }
    }

    this->setMatrix(tmp_matrix.getMatrix());
    unsigned int tmp = m_row;
    m_row = m_column;
    m_column = tmp;
}

void Matrix::setMatrix(unsigned int** mat){
    for(int i=0; i < m_row; i++){
        free(matrix[i]);
        matrix[i]=NULL;
    }
    free(matrix);
    matrix=NULL;
    matrix=mat;
}

unsigned int** Matrix::getMatrix(){
    return matrix;
}

void Matrix::fill(unsigned int x){
    for(int i=0; i<m_row; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<m_column; j++){
            matrix[i][j]=x;
        }
    }
}

void Matrix::fill_x(unsigned int row, unsigned int column, unsigned int x){
    if(row>= m_row||column>=m_column) return;
    matrix[row][column]=x;
}

bool Matrix::isMatch(unsigned int x, unsigned int y){
    if (x==y) return true;
    return false;
}

bool Matrix::isValid(unsigned int row, unsigned int column){
    if(row<m_row&&column<m_column) return true;
    return false;
}

unsigned int Matrix::get_x(unsigned int row, unsigned int column){
    if(isValid(row, column)) return matrix[row][column];
    throw "Invalid matrix index exception.";
}

unsigned int Matrix::getRowNum(){
    return m_row;
}

unsigned int Matrix::getColumnNum(){
    return m_column;
}
```

But if I run this program, the program always crashes if destructor is called after transpose function is called.
Is the problem caused by the `unsigned int** matrix` which has been freed? Can't I reassign the freed pointer to another pointer and then free it again?

**Update:** now I have changed all free() to delete[]. But it still doesn't work. In main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.cpp"

int main(){
    Matrix c(2,3);
    c.fill(30);
    c.transposeMatrix();
    try{
        for(int i=0; i<c.getRowNum(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<c.getColumnNum(); j++){
                cout<<c.get_x(i, j)<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    } catch (const char* e){
        cout<<e;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
[some random number] 0
[some random number] 0
30 30
```

Comment: you can assign a pointer to a memory address that you've allocated and then free it.  You can take that same pointer and assign a different memory address that you've allocated and free that.

Comment: You should do "if(ptr !=0) {free()…}" and you should use delete[] if allocating with new[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem lies on the destructor is being called on tmp_matrix when transpose function end, thus deleting its matrix pointer which is also being pointed by the real matrix container.

It's been fixed. Thanks all. Even though being down voted is a little discouraging. But maybe it really is a stupid question.